# How to exclude Googlebot from log file?

Tags: apache, setenv

I would like to exclude this kind of log entries from `access.log`

```
66.249.78.134 - - [01/Apr/2016:10:56:29 +0000] "POST /get_subtitle HTTP/1.1" 200 416 "https://example.com/?artist=name&track=song" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

So, in my `000-default.conf` and `default-ssl.conf` files I set these rules

```
SetEnvIFNoCase User-Agent "^Googlebot" dontlog
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined env=!dontlog
```

Why Apache continues to log Googlebot activity?

Comment: `SetEnv` is enabled and works with other rules

Comment: Finally I found the solution here http://serverfault.com/questions/680939/trouble-filtering-googlebot-from-apache-access-log and set this rule `SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Googlebot/2.1" dontlog`